# Asus X550CA-XX275H Driver Problems

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, asus, intel

I am completely new to Ubuntu and Linux. I installed everything fast and easy, but I do not know what to do about drivers. I get messages about my graphics card drivers being out of date etc on ubuntu, but I do not know where to find the Linux Asus version of Intel HD 4000 graphics.

Question:

Is my laptop viable with abuntu to work properly(Asus X550CA-XX275H), and can anyone help guide me on if its possible to get an Asus Linux version of Intel HD 4000 (even on windows, intel website still sends to Asus to get their version of the driver.)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

On the website of Intel:

[downloadcenter.intel.com](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?lang=por&changeLang=true&DwnldId=13815)  Here shows the graphic cards supported

[intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.2-linux) Here is the installer

Maybe this can help you...